# PHP: Foreach loop causes the output to have an extra symbol that i don't want

Tags: php

Two different values are imported by html `<input>` tags. They should be displayed like this: `value1:value2`. 
But they display like this instead: `value1:value2:`.
I know what is causing the problem but I don't know how to solve it because I'm just a beginner with PHP.

```
?php
$handle = fopen("text.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, ":");
}

fclose($handle);
exit;
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to store the data in an array, and glue them together with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $tmp[] = htmlentities($value);
}

if($fp = fopen('text.txt', 'a')){
  fwrite($fp, implode(':', $tmp));
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Another solution would be to concat all values to a variable, and strip off the unwanted symbol with `trim()` or `substr()` and then write the value of the variable to file.

Also, it might be wise to check if the file successfully opened and depending on what you do with the saved data, to avoid an XSS attack use htmlentites() if you ever plan to echo it.

Answer (score 2):

In every cycle inside the foreach you add a value and the colon. One option is to add the colon before the value is added and don't add it on the first run. Like this:

```
<?php

    $first = true;
    $handle = fopen("text.txt", "a");

    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {

        if(!$first) {
            fwrite($handle, ":");
            $first = false;
        }
        fwrite($handle, $value);

    fclose($handle);

?>
```

The implode solution from @xorifelse is also nice